# How to order readonly M2M fields in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can't seem to work out how to hook into the queryset of a readonly field in Django admin. In particular I want to do this for an inline admin.

```
# models.py
class Value(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    values = models.ManyToManyField(Value)


class Model(models.Model):
    another_model = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)


# admin.py
class AnotherModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    # How do I order values by 'name'?
    readonly_fields = ('values',)


class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (AnotherModelInline,)
```

Note that this could probably be done by overriding the form and then setting the widget to disabled, but that's a bit of a hack and doesn't look nice (I don't want greyed out multi-select, but a comma-separated list of words.

Comment: Is setting and `ordering` [metadata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options) in the `Value` model, out of the question?

Comment: Oh! I didn't realise there was an `ordering` option on models as well! It's a bit annoying given the extra db costs, but that does work. Add it as an answer and I'll accept. Cheers, @raratiru!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `ordering` [metadata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options) in the `Values` model:

```
class Value(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```